# UIInterfaceOrientation is Landscape but UIView is still on Portrait mode

Tags: ios, avcapturesession

I'm developing an iOS app with latest SDK.

I'm developing an camera app which only supports LandscapeRight orientation.

On Main `ViewController` I have added a `UIView` for `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. In other words, main `ViewController` I have main view, and another view, called `videoPreviewView`, for `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.

I set up `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` on `viewWillAppear:` method:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setUpVideo];
}

- (void)setUpVideo
{
    NSLog(@"Set up video");
    if (DataExchanger.cameraManager != nil)
    {
        UIView *view = [self videoPreviewView];
        CALayer *viewLayer = [view layer];
        [viewLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

        AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:DataExchanger.cameraManager.captureSession];
        CGRect bounds = [view bounds];
        NSLog(@"BOUNDS: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(bounds));

        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:bounds];
        [newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

        [viewLayer insertSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer below:[[viewLayer sublayers] objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}
```

I get this log:

```
BOUNDS: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
```

But `UIInterfaceOrientation` is `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` and with that orientation I would get these values:

```
BOUNDS: {{0, 0}, {480, 320}}
```

And another problem is that I see **video rotated -90 degrees**.

I have found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663913/ios-calayer-orientation-avcapturevideopreviewlayer-doesnt-rotate), but `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation` method is never triggered.

**What's happening? How can I solved this problem?**

Answer (score -1):

1. The default AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer object orientation is landscape!
2. The orientation of the AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer does not change with the orientation of the device. You have to change it manually.
3. To change it manually, you need to call the connection of the preview layer and rotate it:

iOS6:

```
 AVCaptureConnection *previewLayerConnection=self.newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection;
 if ([previewLayerConnection isVideoOrientationSupported])
   [previewLayerConnection setVideoOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

< iOS6:

```
if ([self.newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer isOrientationSupported])   
[self.newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer setOrientation:AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

Comment: I'm working with the latest SDK and I'm supporting iOS 5.0 and above. Which version from your answer do I have to use? But I think your answer doesn't resolved my problem because now I'm using the second option and I'm having this problem.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote 3 of my answers randomly, 3 months after posting; at a minimum, please post a comment with the reason (if there is one).